# Best way to work with GStreamer in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, embedded-linux, gstreamer

I’m not experienced Qt developer so maybe someone could point me to right direction. I try to develop application for embedded system which has GStreamer plugin that allows to use hardware video encoding and encoding accelaration. I looked at GStreamer Application Development Manual  and code looks a little bit ugly.

Maybe there are better ways to work with it in Qt right now. I’m working with Qt 4.8.5, is there anything interesting in Qt5 that could help me?

Comment: Maybe you need qt-gstreamer libs http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/qt-gstreamer.html ?

Comment: Yeah, I would like to use it, but it looks like I won't be able anyway, because it needs at least GStreamer version 0.10.33 and my embedded system's hardware acceleration works only for 0.10.30.